# A Puzzle From Hobson's Plane Trigonometry

Tags: trigonometry

The first question on the first chapter of E. W. Hobson's A Treatise on Plane Trigonometry asks:

*What must be the unit of measurement, that the numerical measure
of an angle may be equal to the difference between its numerical measures as
expressed in degrees and in circular measure?*

Given that the only other angle measure introduced before the question is the grade (1/100 of a right angle), how can one solve this without resorting to negative angles?

Comment: What is "circular measure"? Radians? And what is the "numerical measure" of an angle?

Comment: Yes, circular measure here is radians. As I understand it the numerical measure of an angle is the number representing it in a given unit system i.e the numerical measure of 30$^{\circ}$  is 30.

Comment: If we call the unit a "hobson", I would say that there are $360-2\pi$  hobsons in a circle.

Answer (score 0):

In this system the numerical measure of a right angle is
(90- π/2)
So that (90-π/2) units is a right angle
Therefore unit= 1/(90-π/2) × right angle